# Glusterfs: Initialization of volume 'fuse' failed, review your volfile again

Tags: mount, glusterfs

I have a GlusterFS volume hosted on a remote server. I can mount it from one of my other servers when I try to mount the volume, I get following error

```
[2015-04-15 20:52:24.149773] I [glusterfsd.c:1493:main] 0-/usr/sbin/glusterfs: Started running /usr/sbin/glusterfs version 3.2.6
[2015-04-15 20:52:24.150172] E [mount.c:532:fuse_mount_sys] 0-glusterfs-fuse: cannot open /dev/fuse (No such file or directory)
[2015-04-15 20:52:24.150209] I [mount.c:639:gf_fuse_mount] 0-glusterfs-fuse: direct mount failed (No such file or directory), retry to mount via fusermount
[2015-04-15 20:52:24.152853] E [mount.c:343:fuse_mount_fusermount] 0-glusterfs-fuse: failed to exec fusermount: No such file or directory
[2015-04-15 20:52:24.155692] E [mount.c:343:fuse_mount_fusermount] 0-glusterfs-fuse: failed to exec fusermount: No such file or directory
[2015-04-15 20:52:24.156242] E [mount.c:669:gf_fuse_mount] 0-glusterfs-fuse: mount failed
[2015-04-15 20:52:24.156313] E [xlator.c:1447:xlator_init] 0-fuse: Initialization of volume 'fuse' failed, review your volfile again
```

I use following command to try and mount the volume:

```
# mount -t glusterfs -o defaults,_netdev,rw server:/volumename /mountpoint
```

What do I do to fix it?

Comment: I got to the same problem. Check if you are using the same version for glusterfs client and server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On my old Debian(4.3, etch) machine I had to do `aptitude install fuse-utils` and try mounting again to fix this issue.

Comment: If you could accept your own answer, that would help to clean things up.